# Share folders between three PCs over WIFI network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, file-sharing

What is the process of sharing folders and files to other computers using the WIFI network (D-Link router)?

Can you point me to a good tutorial on how to do this?

I'm in my computer (desktop), and I want to share my files and folders to 2 laptops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set up a **[Homegroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/home-sweet-homegroup-networking-the-easy-way)** if the operating systems on all the computers are Windows 7.

Description:

> *What is HomeGroup?* - HomeGroup is an easy way to share documents, music, pictures, videos, and printers between networked computers at home or in a small business—without a server.

[Windows 7 HomeGroup: Frequently Asked Questions.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449408%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Some other methods:

- [Sharing Files with the Public Folder](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Sharing-files-with-the-Public-folder)
- [Enable file and printer sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Enable-file-and-printer-sharing)
- Consider using **[Sync Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en)** to sync folders.
- Or **[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home)** / **[Windows Live Skydrive](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-skydrive)** for over the internet sharing.

Comment: See a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BWB9pu1T2dQ) of how to use Homegroup

Answer (score 2):

Consider installing Windows [Live Mesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh). This does not require a server machine to be always online, and allows retrieving your files remotely.

Comment: Since I posted this answer, LiveMesh has been replaced by [SkyDrive](http://windows.microsoft.com/skydrive/).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run  type in services.msc
Start the server process
Now right click on the folder you wish to share and go to properties , you should find a tab for sharing .
Enable it .
This folder should now be visible on other machines

Answer (score 0):

Sharing Files will be easy for windows and mac user, you need to install Anysend app in your windows and mac PC,

This link has the Instruction to [how to install anysend and How to send file over the wifi](http://surficle.com/tips/share-files-over-wi-fi-network/).

I Think you will love this app!